# Is there a finite generating set for the Torelli group $T_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

D.Johnson showed in 1983 that for g>2 , the Torelli group $Tg$ has a finite
  set of generators. I have not been able to find out what the case is for g=1,2;
  does anyone know of any result for generating sets for these cases (i.e., are there
  finite generating sets for g=1,2)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the genus 1 case, the Torelli group is trivial.  This is a classical result, see for example Birman's book.

In the genus 2 case, the Torelli group is an infinitely-generated free group. This is a theorem of Geoff Mess. A google search will give you a precise reference.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. When I finally get my act together and figure out how to sign-in, I will give you (and all others) points for your answers. (By then, I will have figured out how this "series of tubes" called the internets works).

Comment: Internets is okay. Try its. :)